# how to do task after xaml page is loaded in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

So I'm working on Windows Phone Project based on music shuffling. I have one [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml) page that display Songs in Queue, code file contain `List<>` that add all song in list but this task take more time.

When i Click a Button to navigate(or show queue)to page my app still remain same page for 4-5 second.

I want that how can I make some code in xaml.cs file that run after page is loaded.

After page loaded I show `Progress Indicator` and when all data completely in List<> elements, I show a Songs.

My code:

```
private void Event()
{
        currentQueueData = MediaPlayer.Queue;
        List<QueueData> boundedQueueData = new List<QueueData>();

        SetProIndicator(true);
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Loading...";

        if (currentQueueData.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = currentQueueData.ActiveSongIndex, k = 0; i < totalqueueCount; i++)
            {
                loadedqueueSongs[k] = currentQueueData[i];
                boundedQueueData.Add(new QueueData()
                {
                    queueSongIndex = k++,
                    queueSongName = currentQueueData[i].Name,
                    queueSongAlbum = currentQueueData[i].Album.Name + ",",
                    queueSongArtist = " " + currentQueueData[i].Artist.Name,
                });
            }
            queueList.ItemsSource = boundedQueueData;
            SetProIndicator(false);
            //queueList.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        }
        else
        {
            boundedQueueData.Add(new QueueData()
            {
                queueSongIndex = 0,
                queueSongName = "Currently Queue Is Empty",
                queueSongAlbum = "",
                queueSongArtist = "",
            });
            queueList.ItemsSource = boundedQueueData;
        }
    }
```

- If it is Possible that Event() function load after MyPage.xaml page is loaded?

Comment: Where is the void Event method located at? Who calls for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments on the question, one possible answer would be to suscribe to the [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event of your page and call the `Event` method from there.

Really simple example:

```
public MyPage() 
{
    this.Loaded += PageLoaded;
}

void PageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Event();
}
```

So what we did is to suscribe to the loaded event on the constructor of the page. By the time the page is loaded, you will be able to call your `Event` method from the callback.